# nestjs entity to dto Is this a best practice?

Tags: nestjs

user.entity.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

create-user-dto.ts

```
export class CreateUserDto extends PartialType(User) {}
```

This code works.
Is this a best practice?

Comment: I don't think so as you're making your DTO too tied with models from database (another layer). Any change that you'll make on entites will broke the clients due to this. To understand this better: https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/enterprise-typescript-nodejs/use-dtos-to-enforce-a-layer-of-indirection/#Using-Data-Transfer-Objects

Comment: I agree to @MicaelLevi. Separated DTOs from your entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it is never a best practice, dtos and entities should not be strictly tied. You are mixing logics.

Just consider for instance, that in this way it comes very hard to add validation on your dto's fields.
Also, a change in the data model not always trigger a change on client's side (e.g. a form at FE side where the form's fields are sent to BE with the dto).

Finally, consider also that sometimes you may need to keep separated the repository from the controller/dtos part because they "live" on different streams. (e.g. AWS lambdas).